# How to change header image dimensions on twenty seventeen theme (on pages other than home page)

Tags: theme-twenty-seventeen

Trying to figure out how to change the height of the header image, as it looks fine on the home page but is cropped awkwardly on every other page.

Answer (score 0):

Please paste below code to your header.php file,

```
<?php 

    if (!is_front_page() ) { 
         echo '<style>.custom-header {height:500px;}</style>';
         } ?>
```

This code will check if current page is not home page then it will assign a new height to the header image. Change the value according to your wish